# How to nest one APIRootView inside another APIRootView?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I tried the following and the `/` endpoint shows only `snippets` route under it. I also want a `nested` route to be shown under it which will send it to another root view containing just `users` route under it. How do I do this?

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"snippets", views.SnippetViewSet)

class ViewSet(ViewSet, nested.APIRootView):
    pass

nested = DefaultRouter()
nested.register(r"users", views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r"nested", ViewSet, basename="nested")

urlpatterns = [url(r"^", include(router.urls))]
```